# Avoiding wasteful memory consumption

Tags: php

Using php.exe 5.2.17.17 on Windows 7, this:

```
include_once('simple_html_dom.php');

function fix($setlink)
{
    $setaddr = $setlink->href;
    $filename="..\\".urldecode($setaddr);
    $set=file_get_contents($filename);  
    $setstr = str_get_html($set);
    // Do stuff requiring whole file
    unset($set);
    unset($setstr);
}

$setindexpath = "..\index.htm";
foreach(file_get_html($setindexpath)->find('a.setlink') as $setlink)
{
    fix($setlink);  
}
```

(relying on external data files) fails thus:

```
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 32 bytes) in [snip]\simple_html_dom.php on line 620
```

"function fix" is a suggestion from the answer to a similar question here. unset() is wishful thinking :-)

How may I avoid the continuing consumption of memory by the strings unused on the next loop iteration? Without defacing the code too much. And while providing the whole file as string.

Comment: i bet DOMDocument would be more performant..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try `$setstr->clear();` before `unset($setstr);`
see http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual_faq.htm#memory_leak

side note: $setstr seems to be a misnomer; it's not a string but the dom repesentation of the html doc.

Comment: " a misnomer" agreed.